# What is the Best way to show Images from database in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a images with hits column in sql table. I want to show images on a webpage like a gallery when an visitor clicks on it it redirect to another page which shows its detail and when visitor clicks on the image it also increase the hits...... I tried it with gridview but that unfullfill the requirements. kindly tell me the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using list view control

[List view control with Images example](http://geekswithblogs.net/omtalsania7/archive/2012/12/27/how-to-create-an-image-grid-with-asp.net-44.5-using.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have Designed this gallery :http://ultimatedesign.in/UserGallery.aspx

Follow this post you get the idea

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/04/display-images-in-aspnet-gridview-from.html